# Tools for Oracle DB migration from AIX to Linux

Tags: oracle, aix, rhel

My colleague running Oracle Database (11g) in AIX and they would like to move this DB to RHEL. I already found [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/dbxptrn.htm#BRADV05432). However I would like to check if someone have already migrated or used any other best tools.

Answer (score 1):

you have several options. As pointed out before, Oracle Data Pump is the easiest approach. It would lift you from every version >=10g upwards (or even back when you use the VERSION= parameter).

The caveat is:
Size of the database - and your downtime requirements.

In terms of larger databases, Transportable Tablespaces is the usual choice. More work as you will have to rebuild meta information such as synonyms, view, plsql, sequences etc - and in your case you'll have to either CONVERT the tablespaces as you are coming from a Big Endiann platform and going to a Little Endiann. DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER could assist you here as it can restore and covert at the same time whereas RMAN will need a 2-phase operation with staging space for it.

You can speed up transportable tablespaces with RMAN Incremental Backups to avoid most of the copy/convert time. And you can ease it with Full Transportable Export/Import (minimum source: 11.2.0.3 - minimum destination: 12.1.0.1) where Data Pump does the manual work of transportable tablespaces.

And of course there are other techniques such as Create-Table-As-Select or Insert-Append-Select options via Database Links and such.

Just see the big slide deck "Upgrade / Migrate / Consolidate to 12.2" for customer examples - and the "Migrate >230Tb in <24 hours" decks on my page: https://mikedietrichde.com/slides/

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Mike, Really awesome. Such a detailed explanations. I have downloaded the pdf and going through as well. Really useful.

Comment: Thanks - and let me know if you need additional advice or clarification.

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you can't just use Oracle Database Pump?

Create the database on RHEL, make sure you use a compatible character set.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm

Comment: Hi Bocas, I will try to use that. I have triedj RMAN before. Will attempt data pump. Thanks.